# What XSLT processor is better to use for small parallel transformations

Tags: performance, xslt

I need to execute lots (abot 100-200) of parallel XML transformation in a cycle. Average XML size is about 5Kb. Relation of used XSL to XML to be parsed is about 0.25, that means that some XMLs are sharing the same XSL. XSL here could be cached, but unfortunately XSL is not stored in File, and generated dynamically within an application.
So what XSLT processor suits better for my case?

p.s. language - Java, transformation final result type - String

thanks in advance

Comment: I don't know that the specific XSLT processor is the critical decision. It would be more important to ensure that the code used to execute the transforms is sound and that you setup test harnesses to evaluate throughput, memory consumption, etc. Then you could evaluate Xerces, Saxon, etc. and see which one performs "better" for your needs. That being said, Saxon is often the "better" processor.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I have fully understood the question, but I'll try.

Firstly, there seem to be two separate questions, which I think are completely orthogonal. First is the question of how to cache your stylesheets: if you are running a transformation more than once then it's a good idea to compile it once and use it repeatedly. In general this isn't a problem, unless there isn't enough memory to cache all the stylesheets in which case you need some kind of LRU strategy.

The second question is your choice of XSLT processor. I think you can use the same caching architecture whichever processor you choose, so this question won't constrain your choice. In the Java world the main free/open-source processors are Xalan (with versions from Apache and embedded in the JDK) and Saxon-HE; since Saxon-HE supports XSLT 2.0 and is usually faster there is little competition. Among paid-for processors the main contenders are IBM's Websphere processor and Saxon-EE; they should both handle this workload with ease, but you're unlikely to consider the IBM product unless you're making a substantial investment in IBM middleware.

(I won't try to hide that I'm the developer of the Saxon product...)